# Node js - Socket.io - client is not connecting to socket.io server

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I am trying to connect to a socket.io-client using this as my `server.js`:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = app.listen(3001);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

app.get('/input', function(req, res){ // This is because in the server the port 3001 is open and I only can use the route 'input' to connect to the node server
   res.send('Hello world');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket) {

   console.log('Client connected.');

   // Disconnect listener
   socket.on('disconnect', function() {
       console.log('Client disconnected.');
   });
});
```

And in my client file:

```
var socket = io.connect('https://urlofthepage:3001', {reconnect: true});
socket.on('connect', function() { console.log('connect'); });

// or (I tried with both) 

var socket = io.connect('https://urlofthepage:3001/input', {reconnect: true});
socket.on('connect', function() { console.log('connect'); });
```

But when I go to `urlofthepage/input` show me

> Hello world

but in the node server **not** show anything like

> Client connected.

And in the page where I have the `client.js` file the console show me

> 3001/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MBSSeZj net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Edit: It's on an online server, which has a wordpress installed, and my `socket.io.js` script is `urlofpage/socket.io/socket.io.js`

AND (I don't know if this matters, it is a test server, and the url has https, but it indicates that it is not secure, we have to change it)

Comment: Which browser are you using ? Could be that browser is not connecting with improper https or browser simply doesn't support sockets.

Comment: I tried with firefox and google chrome, In firefox don't throw any errors but the event io.connect don't show me anything into the node server console.